# Why does waitForMessage not work for a single non-latching message?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need a way to **get the first message that was published after this line of code**.  I am thinking `waitForMessage` seems like a logical choice.  However, it does not seem to be behaving as I expected.

Given the following simple program that waits for messages from a topic a couple of times.

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/Int32.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "listener");

    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    std_msgs::Int32::ConstPtr ret;
    ret = ros::topic::waitForMessage<std_msgs::Int32>("/topic");
    ROS_INFO("%d", ret->data);
    ret = ros::topic::waitForMessage<std_msgs::Int32>("/topic");
    ROS_INFO("%d", ret->data);
    ret = ros::topic::waitForMessage<std_msgs::Int32>("/topic");
    ROS_INFO("%d", ret->data);

    ros::spin();

    return 0;
}
```

I publish with the following non-latching publish

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
import rospy
import std_msgs

if __name__ == "__main__":
        rospy.init_node('publisher')
        pub = rospy.Publisher('/topic', std_msgs.msg.Int32, queue_size=1, latch=False)
        pub.publish(0)
        rospy.spin()
```

`rostopic echo /topic` shows that the message is published correctly.  However, the listener program is still stuck at `waitForMessage` even though the listener program was started before the publishing node.  Why is that the case?

Further testing with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
import rospy
import std_msgs

if __name__ == "__main__":
    i = 0
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        pub = rospy.Publisher('/topic', std_msgs.msg.Int32, queue_size=1)
        rospy.init_node('publisher')
        pub.publish(i)
        i += 1
        rospy.sleep(10)
```

shows that it's always only the first message that is ignored.  The subsequent messages are correctly caught by `waitForMessage`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368646/why-does-waitformessage-not-work-for-a-single-non-latching-message?/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2020-12-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-12-30**:
Seeing your question (and #q368589), perhaps it would be good if you could clarify *why* you "*need a way to get the first message that was published after this line of code*". What is it you're trying to achieve?

Publish-subscribe being a completely asynchronous pattern of communication, implementing anything which requires strict ordering of events in different entities is typically a bit more complex than normal. So things may need a different approach.

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2020-12-30**:
Thanks for the patience and detailed responses,  I am currently running tests in simulation where I rearrange some 200+ objects in gazebo and check if the sensor detects them.  This is repeated many times for many different configurations.  Since I am simulating multiple lidars, getting each sensor measurement takes an incredibly long time.  As such, to speed up my testing, I only get the first sensor reading immediately after rearrangement (which I was thinking to accomplish with `waitForMessage`).  I am currently tracking down an issue where the sensor measurements don't seem to be updated afte rearrangement ([question on gazebosim here](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26198/does-setmodelstate-block-such-that-the-next-sensor-readings-account-for-the-modified-scene/?answer=26214#post-id-26214)) which led me to the questions on `waitForMessage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tl;dr: creating publisher->subscriber connections takes time. You are not giving `waitForMessage(..)` sufficient time, hence it doesn't see any messages on your topic. Result: first message is "lost" and your program then "hangs".

---

Longer explanation:

> Why does waitForMessage not work for a single non-latching message?

From what you show, I don't believe this is caused by `waitForMessage(..)` not working, but again (as in #q368589) has to do with your expectations.

First, to get it out of the way: **there is no central buffer** or message queue maintained between publishers and subscribers. Publishers and subscribers have their **own internal buffer**, but that is not shared with any other nodes, and only exists as long as a node is running.

Consequence of this: messages published *before* a subscriber is online (or: has a connection with a publisher) will **disappear**.

Second: `waitForMessage(..)` does approximately the following (from [here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/f06d584965a80ed6a966456758de20d1a63b6893/clients/roscpp/include/ros/topic.h) and [here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/f06d584965a80ed6a966456758de20d1a63b6893/clients/roscpp/src/libros/topic.cpp#L43-L62)):

1. create a `NodeHandle` (if needed)
2. subscribe to the topic you specify with the message type you specify
3. register a callback, which sets a `bool` to `true` as soon it has received a message
4. returns the message received, or times-out

Note: *approximately*, as the actual implementation is a bit more complicated (uses separate `ros::CallbackQueue`s fi).

From this it should be clear `waitForMessage(..)` essentially does the same thing as any code which subscribes to a topic.

And it also has the exact same limitations and requirements as any other code subscribing to a topic.

As to your observations:

> I publish with the following non-latching publish
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env python  
> import rospy
> import std_msgs
>
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>         rospy.init_node('publisher')
>         pub = rospy.Publisher('/topic', std_msgs.msg.Int32, queue_size=1, latch=False)
>         pub.publish(0)
>         rospy.spin()
> ```
>
> `rostopic echo /topic` shows that the message is published correctly.  However, the listener program is still stuck at `waitForMessage` even though the listener program was started before the publishing node.  Why is that the case?

There are many, many Q&As here on ROS Answers about this (keywords: "*subscriber first message lost*"), but summarising: the cause here is most likely that setting up publisher<->subscriber connections takes time. Even though your listener program was started earlier, the code creating the `ros::Subscriber` in `waitForMessage(..)` simply didn't have sufficient time to subscribe to `/topic` before you published the `0`.

So `waitForMessage(..)` subscribes, but then never sees a message (as you only publish a single one), causing it to "get stuck".

> Further testing with
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env python  
> import rospy
> import std_msgs
>
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     i = 0
>     while not rospy.is_shutdown():
>         pub = rospy.Publisher('/topic', std_msgs.msg.Int32, queue_size=1)
>         rospy.init_node('publisher')
>         pub.publish(i)
>         i += 1
>         rospy.sleep(10)
> ```
>
> shows that it's always only the first message that is ignored.  The subsequent messages are correctly caught by `waitForMessage`

This should now be less of a surprise: while this code goes against best-practices (you should never call `rospy.init_node(..)` nor `rospy.Publisher(..)` in a loop), there is simply more time for `waitForMessage(..)` to create the necessary connections.

> shows that it's always only the first message that is ignored.

that's exactly what you would expect (see some of the existing Q&As about "first message ignored" problems).

All-in-all, I believe again `waitForMessage(..)` does exactly what it is designed for, and the behaviour you observe appears to be by-design.

Whether it is what you expected would be something else.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2